# Book about a boy with a power (his eyes turn gold when he uses it), a little imp thing that helps him, and a girl who also helps him

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

I need help finding this book. I don't remember the name or the author, but I have a vague memory of what is on the cover, and what the story is about. I know that it is a young adult fiction.

It's a story about this boy who has a special power (I think it's time control, I am not too sure.) His eyes turn gold when he uses his power, and he has this little imp (?) that helps him out with danger. There is a second character, a girl, who helps him out a little down the way. The last part of the book is the boy going to his grandma's (?) house where he finds a hallway/door that leads to a different universe (?).

At least that's how I think some parts of the story go? Everything with a question mark I am not 100% sure. I just know that the cover has the boy and the imp thing on his shoulder, and the boys eyes being gold.
I have searched and searched and I cannot seem to find it. If you can help that would be great!

*I know for sure that it is not Shade's Children by Garth Nix but it has a similar story. To me it has a sort if Rick Riordan vibe, and was written sometime in the 2000's (I think 2012-2012).*

Comment: Does anything in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SupernaturalGoldEyes strike you as familiar?